# Enable comments for post when comments meta box removed

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, comments, user-roles

I've hit the issue described in '11:

"[Enable comments for post with comments meta box removed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19542/enable-comments-for-post-with-comments-meta-box-removed)" and I'd like to ask for your help to adapt the mentioned there code to the current wordpress version.

I have a custom post type that must have comments enabled and *contributors* must not be able to disable comments.

I've enabled comments in Settings->Discussion and removed the `commentstatusdiv` meta box with `remove_meta_box()`. After that I've figured out that comments is unset when the meta box is disabled.

I am looking for the way to enforce the comments now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the `'comments_open'` check. It happens inside of the function with the same name, and that function is called in a theme usually like this:

```
comments_open() and comment_form(
    array (
        'comment_notes_after' => ''
    )
);
```

This is how the filter works:

```
add_filter( 'comments_open', 'wpse_98775_comment_check', 10, 2 ); 

function wpse_98775_comment_check( $open, $post_id )
{
    if ( $open )
        return $open;

    if ( 'my_post_type' === get_post_type( $post_id ) )
        return TRUE;

    return $open;
}
```

You could create a [custom plugin with this snippet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/73).

Comment: toscho, if not difficult, could you give a hint. 1. should this work with disabled commentstatusdiv meta box? 2. at what moment comments_open() fires? 3. code doesn't work for me. (I did change my_post_type to the desirable value)

Comment: @anton See my update.

Comment: I have no problems with installation/setup, I've tried your snippet in functions.php, would it really make difference if I put it as a plugin?

Comment: The `comments_open()` check happens in your theme. I have added an example. Make sure you are using a [properly written theme](http://rayofsolaris.net/blog/2012/how-to-check-if-comments-are-allowed-in-wordpress).

Comment: thanks a lot for a theme hint. It was indeed an issue in the theme. Fixed now. And your snippet works flawlessly. THANKS.